# Keep text box in sync with browser location

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm creating a web browser app and would like textbox2 (url address bar) to be in sync with webBrowser1 (web page display) so that what ever the user clicks on the page the address will appear in the box.

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with? You've neglected to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind `textbox2.Text` to `webBrowser1.Source`, as follows:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox2" Text="{Binding ElementName=webBrowser1, Path=Source}" />
<WebBrowser Height="160" Width="160" x:Name="webBrowser1"/>
```

That way, when the user changes the text in `textBox2`, the web browser will also update the page it's pointing to.

Comment: It says that "WebBrowser" type was not found