# Bind textbox to webbrowser?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Could you show me how to bind textBox1 (Address Bar) to webBrowser1 (Web Page) so what ever the user navigates to on the page will show in the box? Or is their another way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962763/keep-text-box-in-sync-with-browser-location. Also, why are you basically having Stackoverflow write your entire application for you step by step? As someone else suggested in another question you asked: buy a book and work through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the events for WebBrowser like DocumentCompleted, Navigating, Navigated,

Please see the sample code , let me know if you have any queries.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();

        }
```

Comment: You can also have this event  private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
        }